# Override object method using Swift protocols and extensions

Tags: swift, swift-extensions, protocol-oriented

I would like to override a method that is declared in a framework and implemented in an extension.

Here's what I've tried :

```
import UIKit

// Code from a dependency

class Object { // UIViewController
    func printSomething() {
        print("something")
    }
}

// My code

protocol SayHelloProtocol {
    func hello()
    func name() -> String
}

extension SayHelloProtocol {
    func hello() {
        print("Hello " + name())
    }

    func name() -> String {
        "someone"
    }
}

class MyHelloObject: Object, SayHelloProtocol {
    override func printSomething() {
        hello()
    }
}

class MyHelloChildObject: MyHelloObject {
    func name() -> String {
        "You"
    }
}

MyHelloObject().printSomething()
MyHelloChildObject().printSomething()
```

This will print :

```
Hello someone
Hello someone
```

But I would like to override the method so it prints :

```
Hello someone
Hello You
```

Is it possible to override a method implemented in an extension ?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @koen I don't really know how to re-phrase, but I would like ```MyHelloChildObject``` to override the name function that is declared in the protocol ```SayHelloProtocol```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works if you add the `name()` function also to `MyHelloObject`:

```
class MyHelloObject: Object, SayHelloProtocol {
    override func printSomething() {
        hello()
    }

    func name() -> String {
        "Someone"
    }
}

class MyHelloChildObject: MyHelloObject {
    override func name() -> String {
        "You"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Even if this works, it's not convenient because it implies to copy-paste the method implemented in the extension to my code. It duplicates code and doesn't guarantee that changes will be applied on both sides. I would like to find a better way

Comment: @Xys I don't think that is possible. This page maybe has some possible workarounds: https://team.goodeggs.com/overriding-swift-protocol-extension-default-implementations-d005a4428bda